# how to check if element is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load an html element on the JSP using java code. It takes time for the page to load this element.
So I am not able to access this element in my jquery ready method.

How do I know if the element is fully loaded?

I tried following code but it did not work.

My element id is "myId"

```
    <div id="myId">
       <input type="text" name="abc"> // this textbox is loaded using java code
    </div>

    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {

             $("#myId").load({

               alert("element loaded");

    }); 
       });
    </script>
```

I also trie javascript defer and window.onload. But it did not help

Comment: The `load` event is only related to things like `<iframe />`, `<img />`, `<script>`, `window`, etc.

Comment: Please add code illustrating, at the very least, the async nature of the textbox's loading. The current code and wording of the question is very imprecise and ambiguous.

Comment: I tried using image as well. But it did not work. I am using jquery version 1.8.1

Comment: _"using java code"_- Java in the browser? Or are you making a JavaScript Ajax request to call a JSP that returns the element in question? Or...? Please show the code that loads that element.

Answer (score 0):

**Java** and **Javascript** is totally different on web page. When you access your web page, the page will be rendered static page such as **common HTML**. So if you want to use js when it be loaded, just put the script like below:

```
<div id="myId">
   <input type="text" name="abc"> // this textbox is loaded using java code
</div>
<script>alert("element loaded");</script>
```